# Trouble with functions not returning what I want

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a code for the game blackjack, where the output will print a list of every value 0-51, followed by a corresponding value in the game blackjack. The code I have looks like this:

```
#cards.py
def cardInfo(cardNumber):
    if cardNumber == 0 or 13 or 26 or 39:  #if the card is an ace
        bjValue = 11                       #the value is 11 of whatever suit
    elif 1 <= cardNumber <= 8:              #if card is 2-9
        bjValue = cardNumber + 1            #the value is itself of clubs
    elif 9 <= cardNumber <= 12:             #if card is 10-king
        bjValue = 10                        #value is 10 of clubs
    elif 14 <= cardNumber <= 21:            #the same as above for the rest
        bjValue = cardNumber - 12           #with respect to higher suits
    elif 22 <= cardNumber <= 25:
        bjValue = 10
    elif 27 <= cardNumber <= 34:
        bjValue = cardNumber - 25
    elif 35 <= cardNumber <= 38:
        bjValue = 10
    elif 40 <= cardNumber <= 47:
        bjValue = cardNumber - 38
    elif 48 <= cardNumber <= 51:
        bjValue = 10
    total = (cardNumber, bjValue) 
    return total

def main():
    for cardValue in range(0,52):
        stuff = cardInfo(cardValue)
        print (stuff)

main()
```

When I run the program, it outputs the first number as it's supposed to, and gives `(0,11)`, `(1,11)` and so forth.

The issue is that the second value isn't returning according to the `if` and `elif` statements in the `cardInfo` function, instead giving the same value for every iteration. It should be returning a value corresponding to the values specified in the if statements, but it just gives back the value given in the first if statement. Can anyone explain why this is or how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`if cardNumber == 0 or 13 or 26 or 39:` will always be `True` so you never reach any `elif`

If you were to write it with or, it would be:

```
if cardNumber == 0 or cardNumber ==  13 or cardNumber == 26 or cardNumber== 39:
```

But it would be better to test for [membership](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/membership_operators_example.htm) and use in  `if cardNumber in {0, 13 , 26, 39}`

Using a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)  `{0, 13 , 26, 39}` testing for membership is `O(1)`.

```
In [6]: i = 10

In [7]: if i == 0 or 1 or 2: # if 1 evaluates to True
   ...:     print(True)
   ...:     
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Your statement `if cardNumber == 0 or 13 or 26 or 39` is equivalent to `if (cardNumber == 0) or (13) or (26) or (39)` where the parens are put around the logical values.

In Python, everything different than empty lists, strings, dictionaries, 0 etc. is considered `True`. Hence, your `if cardNumber == 0 or 13 or 26 or 39` is equivalent to `if cardNumber == 0 or True or True or True` or `if True`.

Perhaps you wanted to write `if cardNumber in [0, 13, 26, 39]` (or, the equivalent but slightly faster `if cardNumber in {0, 13, 26, 39}`). Or, the longer text of `if cardNumber == 0 or cardNumber == 13 or cardNumber == 26 or cardNumber = 39`